# How to get my stackexchange participation by topic

Tags: feature-request, statistics, stack-exchange

Is there a way to get the stats of my stackexchange participation (answers and questions) by topic?

It could be displayed as a pie chart like this one:

[image]

And these stats could be used by stackexchange members to display them on a CV for example.

Comment: I'm certain that there's an API out there that hooks into your user stats and allows you to get that *sort* of information...

Comment: Have a look at [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank's @rene, i didn't know that before.

Comment: This is an interesting graph and the data can be extracted with a SEDE query, but if you want to use this in your CV, I would suggest to prepare the query to reduce the amount of languages to show. Group minor languages in a "Other" field, because no one is really good in so many languages at the same time.

Comment: @Zanon I totally agree with you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of the best places I know of to get information like this easily is [`/users/prediction-data`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data). Click the "Start Download" button, and you'll get a large dump of the data that Stack Overflow uses to decide what questions to show you.

For me, it's an 11,664 line JSON file with all kinds of statistical goodies. For example:

```
"MinorMobileDeveloperKinds": {
   "Android": 0.0767981708049774,
   "IOS": 0.729712426662445,
   "WindowsPhone": 9.99999997475243E-07
},
```

and

```
"TechStacks": {
   "FullStackWebPHP": 0.193095684051514,
   "FullStackWebRubyOnRails": 0.543149530887604,
   "FullStackWebMicrosoft": 0.166872814297676,
   "FullStackWebNodeJS": 0.0585749447345734,
   "FullStackWebPython": 0.10462049394846,
   "FullStackWebJava": 0.127195924520493,
   "FullStackWebWordpress": 0.0739234611392021,
   "BackEndWebCloud": 0.0835744813084602,
   "IntegrationSalesforce": 0.00049887876957655,
   "IntegrationSharePoint": 0.00947869662195444,
   "DesktopWindows": 0.0158113874495029,
   "DesktopOSX": 0.70925372838974,
   "DesktopLinux": 9.99999997475243E-07,
   "DatabaseAdministrationOracle": 0.00723374215885997,
   "DatabaseAdministrationSQLServer": 0.0049887876957655,
   "DatabaseAdministrationMySQL": 0.171115428209305
},
```

It also contains, apparently, the tags of the questions you view on many different Stack Exchange network sites. It's a cool file, have fun with it!

If you're looking for more fine-grained information on *what* you've posted, try the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com). It's updated weekly and contains publicly available data, which you can query if you know a little bit of SQL.